# Facebook share dialog PostId is null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sharer

I am sharing a video on FB via share dialog in Android. The sharing works perfectly fine. However, FB post id returns null. The callback returns even before the video is uploaded. Please let me know, if I missing something. Below is my code.

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private ShareDialog shareDialog;

    public TestFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static TestFragment newInstance(String path, String json) {
        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        // this part is optional
        shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                Timber.d("result.getPostId() :: " + result.getPostId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Timber.d("Facebook : Cancelled");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Timber.d(e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.facebookShare)
    public void share() {
        Timber.d("share button pressed");
        if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareVideoContent.class)) {
            Timber.d("showing share dialog");
            shareDialog.show(getVideoContent());
        } else {
            Timber.d("unable to show the share dialog");
        }
    }

    private ShareVideoContent getVideoContent() {
        Timber.d(mVideoMetadata.getVideoId());

        ShareVideo shareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder()
                .setLocalUrl(Uri.parse("... file ..."))
                .build();
        ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
                .setVideo(shareVideo)
                .build();

        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Facing the same problem at present

Comment: A post ID will only be returned if your app implements Facebook Login and requests the 'publish_actions' permission. Is this requested by your app?

Comment: @subeeshb Thanks for this pointer. At this moment, I haven't implemented FB login. I will update once, I implement FB login.

Comment: mukeikh, have u solved the problem?

Comment: it requires FB login before accessing the feature.

Comment: hello, I used FB login before posted and still couldn't get postID. is there any other thing that you added?

Answer (score 0):

shareDialog.show(shareContent, ShareDialog.Mode.FEED);
Set mode to ShareDialog.Mode.FEED. 
 
It's working for me .

[Here's example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNYaB.png)

Answer (score 0):

**When Login Success With Facebook Then Call This Method 
shareOnFacebook()**

private void shareOnFacebook(){

```
    ShareLinkContent shareContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("The Simpson!")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.codecube.in/airbucks-project"))
            .build();

    mFacebookShareDialog.show(shareContent, ShareDialog.Mode.FEED);

    mFacebookShareDialog.registerCallback( this.callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            Log.v("MyApp", "Share success!"); //Showed if I press the share or the cancel button
            String postID = result.getPostId();
            Log.v("MyApp", "Share success!" +result.getPostId());                        
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.v("MyApp", "Share canceled"); //Only showed when I press the close button
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.v("MyApp","Share error: " + e.toString());
        }    
    });
    mFacebookShareDialog.show(shareContent, ShareDialog.Mode.FEED);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```